# Haskell Foreign function interface binding to libsodium - bad signature

Tags: c, haskell, ffi, libsodium

I am making a binding to [libsodium](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/) so I can sign bytestrings in Haskell, but the signature does not match the one created by C for the same message and secret key.

I am binding to this function in libsodium:

```
int crypto_sign_detached(unsigned char *sig, unsigned long long *siglen,
                         const unsigned char *m, unsigned long long mlen,
                         const unsigned char *sk);
```

The docs say:

> The crypto_sign_detached() function signs the message m whose length is mlen bytes, using the secret key sk, and puts the signature into sig, which can be up to crypto_sign_BYTES long.
>
> The actual length of the signature is put into siglen if siglen is not NULL.
>
> It is safe to ignore siglen and always consider a signature as crypto_sign_BYTES bytes long: shorter signatures will be transparently padded with zeros if necessary.

crypto_sign_BYTES is 64.

Here is the Haskell code (sorry about the length, but it is as short as possible):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Base16 as B16
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal as Bi
import qualified Foreign as F
import qualified Foreign.C.Types as T
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)

secretkey :: B.ByteString
secretkey = B.pack [0x34, 0xEB, 0xA3, 0x9F, 0xC5, 0xA1, 0xB4, 0x1D,
                    0x64, 0x12, 0xCE, 0xC3, 0xD2, 0x0A, 0x7F, 0xA8,
                    0x24, 0x24, 0x2A, 0xDC, 0x1E, 0x6C, 0x04, 0x48,
                    0xCE, 0x91, 0xB3, 0xC4, 0x84, 0xCC, 0x7A, 0xC6]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    status <- c_sodium_init
    case status of
      0 ->
        case sign "test" secretkey of
          Right sig -> do
            print $ B16.encode sig
          Left err -> print err
      _ -> putStrLn "Could not initialize."

crypto_sign_BYTES :: Int
crypto_sign_BYTES = 64

packCString :: Int -> F.Ptr F.Word8 -> IO B.ByteString
packCString len cstr = create len $ \p -> Bi.memcpy p cstr len

create :: Int -> (F.Ptr F.Word8 -> IO ()) -> IO B.ByteString
create l f = do
  fp <- Bi.mallocByteString l
  F.withForeignPtr fp f
  return $! Bi.PS fp 0 l

foreign import ccall unsafe "sodium.h crypto_sign_detached"
  c_crypto_sign_detached
    :: CUString
    -> F.Ptr T.CULLong
    -> CUString
    -> T.CULLong
    -> CUString
    -> IO T.CInt

sign :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString -> Either Int B.ByteString
sign message secretKey = unsafePerformIO $
  useAsCString message $ \messagePtr ->
  useAsCString secretKey $ \secretKeyPtr ->
  F.allocaBytes crypto_sign_BYTES $ \sig -> do
    status <- c_crypto_sign_detached
                  sig
                  F.nullPtr
                  messagePtr
                  (fromIntegral $ B.length message)
                  secretKeyPtr
    case status of
      0 -> do
        packed <- packCString crypto_sign_BYTES $ F.castPtr sig
        return $ Right packed
      errCode -> return $ Left $ fromIntegral errCode

foreign import ccall unsafe "sodium.h sodium_init"
  c_sodium_init :: IO T.CInt

type CUString = F.Ptr T.CUChar

useAsCString :: B.ByteString -> (CUString -> IO a) -> IO a
useAsCString (Bi.PS fp o l) action =
  F.allocaBytes (l+1) $ \buf ->
    F.withForeignPtr fp $ \p -> do
      Bi.memcpy buf (p `F.plusPtr` o) (fromIntegral l)
      F.pokeByteOff buf l (0::F.Word8)
      action (F.castPtr buf)
```

Here is the C code:

```
#include <sodium.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    if (sodium_init() < 0) {
        printf("could not initialize");
    }

    unsigned char message[4] = "test";
    unsigned char sk[32] = {0x34, 0xEB, 0xA3, 0x9F, 0xC5, 0xA1, 0xB4, 
                            0x1D, 0x64, 0x12, 0xCE, 0xC3, 0xD2, 0x0A,
                            0x7F, 0xA8, 0x24, 0x24, 0x2A, 0xDC, 0x1E,
                            0x6C, 0x04, 0x48, 0xCE, 0x91, 0xB3, 0xC4, 
                            0x84, 0xCC, 0x7A, 0xC6};

    unsigned char sig[crypto_sign_BYTES];
    
    crypto_sign_detached(sig, NULL, message, 4, sk);

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<64; i++)
    {
        printf("%02X", sig[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The Haskell output is:

```
"17aa8f20476a8e70f860707b8fd7f8f78ffd778690a755ddf3a432a81786ea3dea9efa2028d8896efaf1efe428781b3af83ab0450fc94a2ae6ec2c1a34ca830e"
```

The C output is:

```
17AA8F20476A8E70F860707B8FD7F8F78FFD778690A755DDF3A432A81786EA3D4B54ECDA53E7774C43BE7098A96C39A59664953E40AFFB54ACB84E09CBFF4E07
```

Why do these signatures only match for the first 32 bytes of the 64?  If it helps, I have put the code on [Github](https://github.com/8n8/libsodiumIssue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES` is 64, not 32. Make your secret key this long, and the C and Haskell code will agree with each other.

Comment: I have just run the Haskell code again, but the signature is the same as the one in the question.

Comment: But it does come out differently each time for the C code.

Comment: @5ndG Hm. Okay. There are also some comments in the documentation that call my answer into question: "The Ed25519 system was designed to compute deterministic signatures. Non-deterministic (but also non-standard) signatures can be produced by compiling libsodium with the `ED25519_NONDETERMINISTIC` macro defined." Is it possible the libsodium your C code is linking against and the libsodium your Haskell code is linking against were built differently?

Comment: @5ndG Got it. I was barking up a completely wrong tree. I've corrected my answer... and this time I tested it before spouting off. ;-)

Comment: Consider using the saltine library's bindings if this is for more than play.

Comment: @ThomasM Why? Is it risky to do it myself?

Comment: @ThomasM I am a bit wary of Saltine, because of the "Please try it out, but don't just yet stake your life or job on it." at the top of the README on its Github page. I'm finding it difficult to find a crypto library in Haskell that I can trust, and that doesn't require me to make decisions that I'm not qualified to make.

Comment: I'd say it is more risky to do it yourself, yes. Having put saltine through the paces, and fixed a security-critical bug I'd say the warning was justified.  Perhaps oddly, I came away from the experience with slightly more faith in saltine (the internals aren't scary).  If I were putting live on the line then I'd probably invest in Liquid Haskell + Saltine instead of building a new "saltine" (and assuming Haskell to start with).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Yes I'll try LH + Saltine.  I also thought of generating a load of test data from C, and using it to test Saltine with, to check that Saltine always produces the same results.